# How to handle different operations defined at runtime on object(s)

Tags: c++, oop

I have been running into some design problems on my project that I am hoping to get some help with. I have come up with an example that I think outlines the problem I am encountering. I am new to software design, so forgive me if I completely missed something.

In this example say I have:

```
struct Book {
    std::string author_first_name;
    std::string author_last_name;
    int year_published;
    double price_in_dollars;
 };

class BookCase {
    std::vector<Book> all_books;
    // Rest of class implementation
 }
```

I read in all the books from a file, or more than one file and store them in BookCase. Then I want to do a bunch of operations on BookCase, defined at runtime, this is where I am stuck.

Say the user wants to sort the books by author and then export, the next time sort by first name, or by price, or wants to add a new operation maybe remove books published before year X.

My questions are:

1. Where is the best place to put these operations. I could easily add these operations to BookCase:

   ```
   class BookCase {

       void SortByLastNameAscending();
       void SortByLastNameDescending();
       void SortByPriceAscending();
    // etc...};
   ```

   I know this is wrong, this will bloat the class, and everytime a new operation is added the class has to be changed. I could have something like a class or even a namespace "BookCaseProcessor", that has all the operations and add new ones there. Is there a more elegant way to handle something like this, perhaps a design principle that I am missing.
2. How do I string together the operations in a nice way. Say the user wants to RemoveBooksBeforeYear(), RemoveBooksThatCostLessThan(), SortByLastNameDescending(). The next time they run they want to only do one thing, or 10 things. Right now the only solution I can think of is just a bunch of if statements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do this is to use std::function.

given that you implement the various operations like so:

```
void SortByLastNameAscending(BookCase&) {...}
void SortByLastNameDescending(BookCase&) {...}
void SortByPriceAscending(BookCase&) {...}
```

You can populate a simple list of operations to execute:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(BookCase&)>> pipeline;

//populate the pipeline
if(user_choice == "sort") {
  pipeline.emplace_back(SortByLastNameAscending);
}
```

And execute them in sequence:

```
BookCase data;
for(auto& op : pipeline) {
  op(data);
}
```

Comment: Would you have another class or namespace where those functions are implemented, or would they be implemented in BookCase?

Comment: The beauty of using std::function<> is that these functions can be implemented pretty much wherever. The modern way of doing things would be to have them functions be simply free-floating in a namespace. This way, users of the functionality can create more functions without having to alter the original class.

Comment: This is outrageously convoluted. It's not going to work in this case anyway as the functions would need to access the private members (see SergeyA's answer for a similar answer accounting for this problem).

Answer (score 1):

Software design questions are seldom black-and-white, and are often subjective. I will try to offer my suggestions with some explanations.

I see nothing wrong with putting supporting operations into `BookCase` itself. There is no clearer place to provide class contract than the class! Any `Processor`-style addition will only make the interface less clear. You will quickly find the need to make this `Processor` a friend of the class, and than you will see that it is much worse than just having your sort method right in the `BookCase`.

I probably would not create multiple `SortBy<Field>...` methods, but instead, would templatize it on something or use tag dispatch, but it is probably more of the taste preference. However, I would certainly discourage from different versions of 'Ascending vs Descending'. This makes no sense, use 'ascending/descending' as a tag argument to the sort function.

Comment: Adding the methods right to BookCase would not be bad practice in terms of design, does not violate the SOLID principles? 
For the second part, how would you handle the different types of sorting then? What If the user wants it A-Z or Z-A. And the different type of operations that are not sorting based (remove books that cost less or more than X dollars)?

Comment: @user6768079 Like I said, ascending/descending sort would be handled by tag to the sort function. As for different operations, I would try to figure it out. For example, for removals, I would have a removal function which takes a functor.

Comment: For removal, there's potentially std::remove_if

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that your class is named `BookCase`. That's not what the class is. A bookcase and more generally a library should have one definite order.

What you're actually dealing with is a `BookSelection`. (Depending on what you want to do you may still need to keep the `BookCase`; or the file can be the bookcase.)

Also, since the focus is on sorting and modification, `list`s may make more sense here than `vector`s.